# How to estimate marginal effect of x across categories that are not controlled for in a logestic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, econometrics, stata

I am trying to estimate the partial/marginal effect of variable x in a logit regression across a range of categories that I have not specifically used as control variable. More specifically, I have a regression of say $$ \log(\frac{p_{ijt}}{1-p_{ijt}}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1.X_{ijt} + T_{j} + \varepsilon_{ijt} $$
where $p_{ijt}$ denotes the prob of success for unit $i$ in category $j$ and time $t$. In the regression, I control for the type of category using $T$ (say 6 digits industry definition) and cluster the standard errors at a broader category definition (say 2 digits industry definition).

I am interested to estimate the partial/marginal effect of X across broader category definition (i.e. 2 digits industry). If I control for it, it should be straitforward to estimate it in STATA (or perhaps in other softwares) using $margins$ command , but since I do not directly control for it in the regression, I cannot simply estimate the partial/marginal effect of X across that. Any suggestion?

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Phrased differently (without fancy symbols :-)) you are conducting logistic regression independently for each i, j and t. However, when simply adding something then to a single case (you add $T_j$) does not change the result of the logistic regression: In the minimalization process, logistic regression can simply decide to remove that $T_j$ by adapting the bias... you seem to have some kind of interaction between the different i, j and t but I still do not fully get what you actually want to do... If you want to proceed in this way then why not just taking the factor $\beta_1$ as 'importance'?

Comment: This is a stadard way of defining a logit type regression. You can alternatively assume that you regresss a binary outcome variable on X and T. The indices i,j and t denotes a unit i in a 4 digits industry j at time t, so they are not independent. I simply want to know how can I define the partial/marginal effect of X on P across different 2 digits industry level noting that I have not directly controlled for 2 digits industry (only controlled for 4 digits industry i.e. T) in the regression.